# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string - python

Tags: python

This is the part of the code:

```
    print("User would be added sudo access")
    comment = raw_input("Enter comment for sudo entry ")
    group_name = raw_input("Enter sudo group name ")

    edit_verdad = "vd edit -u '+module.sudo.alias.'%s' = '%s'' \
                   -u '+module.sudo.ent.'%s'.cmd = ALL' \
                   -u '+module.sudo.ent.'%s'.comment = '%s'' \
                   -u '+module.sudo.ent.'%s'.host = ALL' \
                   -u '+module.sudo.ent.'%s'.passwd = 0' \
                   -u '+module.sudo.ent.'%s'.user = '%s'' \
                    '%s'"  %(group_name, options.username, group_name, comment, group_name, group_name, group_name, group_name, options.hostname)
    print(edit_verdad)
```

variable options.hostname and options.username have the right values from opt parse.

when i run the script i get something like:

```
[loclhost]$ ./add_sudo_access.py -u rocky -n somehostname.xxx.yyy.com
User would be added sudo access
Enter comment for sudo entry ticket 123
Enter sudo group name sudoadm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./add_sudo_access.py", line 50, in <module>
    '%s'"  %(group_name, options.username, group_name, comment, group_name, group_name, group_name, group_name, options.hostname)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I suggest you make more careful counts of how many times `'%s'` appears in the string and how many variables you're interpolating into that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 10 arguments in format but you passed 9 value in tuple.

Please try this

```
edit_verdad = "vd edit -u '+module.sudo.alias.'%s' = '%s'' \
                   -u '+module.sudo.ent.'%s'.cmd = ALL' \
                   -u '+module.sudo.ent.'%s'.comment = '%s'' \
                   -u '+module.sudo.ent.'%s'.host = ALL' \
                   -u '+module.sudo.ent.'%s'.passwd = 0' \
                   -u '+module.sudo.ent.'%s'.user = '%s'' \
                    '%s'"  %(group_name, options.username, group_name, comment, group_name, group_name, group_name, group_name, options.hostname, "LAST VARS")
```

Now you have 10 arguments for 10 `%s`.

You can replace `LAST VARS` with your value. Or remove 1 `%s` from your string.

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully counts the number of '%s' in your string you get the number 10. Unfortunately in `%(..)` list you have only 9 elements. Either you got an extra `%s` or you miss one value in `%(..)` list.